# Jersey 404 on two Resource Classes with similar @Path annotations

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I have a RESTful Web service, using Drop Wizard 0.8.5 with Jersey 2.21. I have a resource class with is annotated with:

`@Path("/mysite/somepath")`

This class contains various methods, such as @GETs, @PUTS, etc., all working just fine.

Now, I have another resource class that is annotated with `@Path("/mysite")`. Within this resource class I have a need to add a few methods annotated with paths such as the following:

```
@Path("/somepath/dothis")
@Path("/somepath/dothat")
```

The resource classes all register just fine. However, when I make a call to the second class I get a 404, as it appears Jersey is looking for these methods in my first class. Is there a way to resolve this issue, other than changing my @Path annotations to avoid this naming conflict?

Comment: honestly dont you think its a bad idea to have two classes with the same path name??

Comment: @JasonZ Yes, the two classes were merged since I posted this question. I was just curious as to what the crux of the issue was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jersey presumes each class has unique `@Path` expression associated with it. If you want to use the same `@Path` variable to two different resources, you either use two different path names, or you can combine the two classes into one class.